# C# LINQ and calculations involving large datasets

Tags: c#, linq, performance, list

This is more of a technical "how-to" or "best approach" question.

We have a current requirement to retrieve records from the database, place them into an 'in-memory' list and then perform a series of calculations on the data, i.e. maximum values, averages and some more specific custom statistics as well.

Getting the data into an 'in-memory' list is not a problem as we use NHibernate as our ORM and it does an excellent job of retrieving data from the database. The advice I am seeking is how should we best perform calculations on the resulting list of data.

Ideally I would like to create a method for each statistic, MaximumValue(), AverageValueUnder100(), MoreComplicatedStatistic() etc etc. Of course passing the required variables to each method and having it return the result. This approach would also make unit testing a breeze and provide us with excellent coverage.

Would there be a performance hit if we perform a LINQ query for each calculation or should be consolidate as many calls to each statistic method in as few LINQ queries as possible. For example it doesn't make much sense to pass the list of data to a method called AverageValueBelow100 and then pass the entire list of data to another method AverageValueBelow50 when they could effectively be performed with one LINQ query.

How can we achieve a high level of granularity and separation without sacrificing performance?

Any advice ... is the question clear enough?

Comment: The best approach would be to perform the queries against the database where you have the benefit of indexes to improve performance

Comment: really? so rather than process 'in-memory' we would be better to query the database. some of the calculations are quite complicated so i am not entirely sure this would be the best approach.

Comment: Most often databases are quicker

Comment: @Rowen The database does it 'in-memory' too but it has extra information like the built in indexes that can make some of the look ups when performing the calculations with a much lower time complexity.

Comment: Linq cant be faster than the DB per definition. How could it be? It just executes SQL on it. Cant be faster than executing the same SQL on the DB. Instead of pulling in Lists you might want to build up IQueryables which you can "stack" different Linq Expressions on and defer execution so you only execute what you want and is relevant on data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the calculation, it may be best to do it in the database. If it is signifcantly complex that you need to bring it in as objects and encur that overhead, you may want to avoid multiple iterations over your result set. you may want to consider using Aggregate. See http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2009/12/09/demystifying-linq-aggregates.aspx for a discussion if it. You would be able to unit test each aggregate separately, but then (potentially) project multiple aggregates within a single iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I dont agree that it is best "to do it all in the database".

Well written Linq Queries will result in good SQL queries being executed against the database, which should be good enough performance wise (if you are not going to do dwh stuff). This is assuming you are using the Linq Provider for NHibernate and not Linq to Objects.

It does look good, you can change it easily and keeps your business logic in one place.

If that is too slow for your needs, you might check the SQL code created and tweak your linq queries, are try to precompile them, and in the end you can still go back to writing the beloved stored procedures - and start to spread your business logic all over the place.

Will there be a performance hit? Yeah, you might lose a few millisecs, but is that worth the price you have to pay for separating your logic?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to do it all in the database. I was just advising against getting all the data in memory and then performing what would effectively be Linq to objects queries against that.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "I would like to create a method for each statistic" concern, I would suggest you to build a kind of statistician class. Here is some pseudo code to express the idea :

```
class Statistician
{
    public bool MustCalculateFIRSTSTATISTIC { get; set; }   // Please rename me!
    public bool MustCalculateSECONDSTATISTIC { get; set; }  // Please rename me!

    public void ProcessObject(object Object) // Replace object and Rename
    {
        if (MustCalculateFIRSTSTATISTIC)
            CalculateFIRSTSTATISTIC(Object);

        if (MustCalculateFIRSTSTATISTIC)
            CalculateSECONDSTATISTIC(Object);
    }

    public object GetFIRSTSTATISTIC() // Replace object, Rename
    { /* ... */ }
    public object GetSECONDSTATISTIC() // Replace object, Rename
    { /* ... */ }

    private void CalculateFIRSTSTATISTIC(object Object) // Replace object
    { /* ... */ }
    private void CalculateSECONDSTATISTIC(object Object) // Replace object
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

Would I have to do this, I would probably try to make it generic and use collections of delegates instead of methods, but since I don't know your context, I'll leave it to that. Also note that I only used Object members of object class, but that's only because I'm not suggesting you to use DataRows, Entities, or what not; I'll leave that to the other folks that know more then me on the subject!